# SQL How to JOIN a child table without increasing the number of rows returned in the query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have a parent table A, with 2313 rows. It has a child table B, with a one to many relationship.

I'm creating a view to display information about table A. It is critical this view does not repeat any rows from table A. However, I also need it to pull some info from its child table B.

First I tried using a LEFT JOIN to table B, but increased the rows returned (~5k). Currently I am trying to use a subquery with MAX and GROUP BY to only return information from 1 child row, but it is not working successfully, and returning ~3k rows.

I do not care which of the child rows is used to display information. I just need to ensure I only have 1 (to avoid repeating the parent in the VIEW).

```
SELECT 
    -- Rows from Table A, and enum tables (works fine).
    t1.device_name_AF                AS 'DEVICE NAME',
    e1.issuance_name                 AS 'ISSUANCE',
    t1.revision_number               AS 'REVISION',
    t1.description_combo_AF          AS 'INSTRUMENT DESCRIPTION',
    t2.PCDT_AF                       AS 'PCDT',
    t2.device_description            AS 'PCDT DESCRIPTION',
    c2.company_name                  AS 'VENDOR',
    t2.all_parts_used_AF             AS 'PARTS',
    e2.floor_key_AF                  AS 'FLOOR',
    -- t1.zone_location                 AS 'ZONE',
    e3.system_acronym                AS 'SYSTEM',
    t1.equipment_type                AS 'EQUIPMENT TYPE',
    t1.system_process_number         AS 'SYSTEM PROCESS NUMBER',
    e4.device_acronym                AS 'INSTRUMENT TYPE',
    t1.parallel_equipment_designator AS 'PARALLEL EQUIPMENT DESIGNATOR',
    t1.pnid_drawing                  AS 'P&ID',
    t1.location_drawing              AS 'LOCATION DRAWING',
    e5.model_status                  AS 'BIM STATUS',
    t1.submittal_number              AS 'SUBMITTAL NUMBER',
    t1.submittal_status              AS 'SUBMITTAL STATUS',
    e6.company_name                  AS 'PROCURED BY',
    e7.company_name                  AS 'INSTALLED BY',
    e8.company_name                  AS 'WIRED BY',
    t1.instance_comment              AS 'DEVICE COMMENT',
    e9.mounting_description          AS 'MOUNTING STYLE',
    t1.IO_point_count_AF             AS 'ASSOCIATED IO COUNT',


    -- Rows from Child Table B
    sub1.lookup_rack_num_AF           AS 'RACK',
    sub1.lookup_slot_num_AF           AS 'SLOT',
    sub1.channel                      AS 'POINT',


    t1.location_N_S                  AS 'LOCATION N/S',
    t1.location_E_W                  AS 'LOCATION E/W',
    t1.location_room                 AS 'LOCATION ROOM'
    
    FROM device.instance                    AS t1
    LEFT JOIN device.device_type_catalog    AS t2 ON t2.ID_auto = t1.PCDT_ID
    LEFT JOIN controls.IO_table             AS t3 ON t3.parent_device_ID = t1.ID_auto

    LEFT JOIN enum.issuance                 AS e1 ON e1.ID_auto = t1.issuance_ID
    LEFT JOIN enum.building_floor           AS e2 ON e2.ID_auto = t1.floor_ID
    LEFT JOIN enum.process_system           AS e3 ON e3.ID_auto = t1.system_ID
    LEFT JOIN enum.device_name              AS e4 ON e4.ID_auto = t1.instrument_type_ID
    LEFT JOIN enum.BIM_status               AS e5 ON e5.ID_auto = t1.BIM_status_ID
    LEFT JOIN enum.company                  AS e6 ON e6.ID_auto = t1.procured_by_ID
    LEFT JOIN enum.company                  AS e7 ON e7.ID_auto = t1.installed_by_ID
    LEFT JOIN enum.company                  AS e8 ON e8.ID_auto = t1.wired_by_ID
    LEFT JOIN enum.mounting_style           AS e9 ON e7.ID_auto = t1.mounting_style_ID

    LEFT JOIN enum.company                  AS c2 ON c2.ID_auto = t2.vendor_ID

    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
        MAX(x3.lookup_rack_num_AF) AS lookup_rack_num_AF, 
        MAX(x3.lookup_slot_num_AF) AS lookup_slot_num_AF, 
        MAX(x3.channel) AS channel, 
        x3.parent_device_ID 
        FROM controls.IO_table AS x3
        GROUP BY x3.parent_device_ID
    ) 

    AS sub1 ON sub1.parent_device_ID = t1.ID_auto
    WHERE (t1.PCDT_ID IS NOT NULL) AND (t2.is_instrument = 1)
```

Comment: Aliases like `a` is for `Customer` and `b` is for `Account`, or `t1` is for `Purchase` and `t2` is for `Transaction` aren't helpful for you or others that want to read your code. Use meaningful and *consistent* aliases for your objects. I suggest a read of [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

Comment: Why do you `LEFT JOIN` to "`T2`" when you require a column from it to have a non-`NULL` value?

Comment: Oh, @ThomA is there a better solution I should be using?
I had it setup this way because all Instruments are Devices, but not all Devices and Instruments. Here I'm making a report of only Instruments. The catalog will tell me if it's an instrument or not.

Catalog -> Instance -> IO Point

Comment: Have you tried removing the join to ( ) sub1 to see if the extra 700 rows are coming from somewhere else?

Comment: @Josh, Thank you! This was my issue. The subquery was working properly, but I forgot to comment out my previous join to t3 (The IO Table).

Comment: @Josh is there a way I can mark your comment as the solution, or do I just close the question?

Comment: when you have such problem, you start withe the first table and then add one by one, till you find the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are thinking correctly here - and your ( ) sub1 subquery appears that it will logically only produce 1 row. Therefore that join should not increase the rows at all, and so I would try removing that section to see if the 700 extra rows might be coming from one of the other joins.